# Designing a light-weight accounting application

Tags: software-design, accounting

I am designing a light-weight accounting application that suits small to medium
business (eg .shops), any reference to materials that help or ideas from anyone who did this kind of software  before would be great.
NOTE : reference to a (C# preferably) library would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many open-source accounting applications out there; i'm not sure if this one was done in c# but here's a link:

[FrontAccounting(accounting software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FrontAccounting)  Note: This one is a web-app.

The links for downloading the software are all the way at the bottom of the page in the "references" section.  Hope that helps!

List of other accounting softwares(open source): 
[Other Softwares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_and_open_source_software_packages)  Scroll down to "Finance".

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep it generic as possible and consider the adoption a plugin framework to forsee further extension. A good business analysis eventually is a prerequisite.